What is the typescript equivalent of Option<T> in anchor?
The title says it all: If my anchor instruction expects an Option<T> to be passed what do I need to send in typescript for None and Some<T> respectively? I checked the docs but couldn't find any info on this.

For None I've tried undefined, null,[undefined], [null], {} but all of these result in InstructionDidNotDeserialize

If you mean the transaction data (arguments) then null works fine for me.
In particular for recent Anchor project we pass configuration options either with value (to be configured) or None (to not be configured).
The program arguments are defined as:
https://github.com/marinade-finance/validator-bonds/blob/main/programs/validator-bonds/src/instructions/config/configure_config.rs#L7
The Anchor TS IDL is generated as:
https://github.com/marinade-finance/validator-bonds/blob/contract-v1.4.0/packages/validator-bonds-sdk/generated/validator_bonds.ts#L2936
And the Anchor TS types are loaded and used in the following way to pass null at on-chain call.

https://github.com/marinade-finance/validator-bonds/blob/contract-v1.4.0/packages/validator-bonds-sdk/src/sdk.ts#L46 (fetching type)
https://github.com/marinade-finance/validator-bonds/blob/contract-v1.4.0/packages/validator-bonds-sdk/src/instructions/configureConfig.ts#L67 (creating the ix)


null works now for me, so the error I was facing stemmed from something else. Thanks for the elaborate answer!
